# Power meter design

Tags: transformer, power-electronics, flyback, power-meter

We want to design a 3 phase power meter that measures AC voltage, current, frequency and calculates power factor.

We want to use a voltage transformer and a current transformer for each phase.

My question is about the voltage transformer:

1. Should we drive it with a switching transistor like in switching ps to benefit from small transformer size?
2. Or can we just apply 50-60 Hz source to its primary and not worry about transformer size, since the current drawn from secondary by voltage measurement stage (voltage divider, op amp) will be very low?

We intend to use transformers removed from phone chargers, how can we decide?

Our initial idea is to use 4 voltage transformers, the 4th is for powering the entire circuit (microcontroller, ICs, display) from one of the phases.

Comment: "We intend to use transformers removed from phone chargers, how can we decide?" never thought about whether that was possible, I must admit! Assuming you'll not have a datasheet for the custom transformers you typically find in such SMPS, how will you figure out how the input/output voltage curve incl phase shift looks?

Comment: Check out https://openenergymonitor.org/ where this has all been sorted out already.

Comment: `We want to use a voltage transformer and a current transformer for each phase.` is there a specific reason why you're thinking about using a transformer for voltage measurement? You can simply measure with direct contact using only a few resistors and maybe an op-amp.

Comment: @RohatKılıç I have seen a cicuit example that uses a voltage divider, but I thought that isolation is necessary for safety

Comment: @MarcusMüller how will you figure out how the input/output voltage curve incl phase shift looks? By testing ?

Comment: @IssamH I wouldn't. Too much uncertainty for too little gain, under too much effort. Don't use random switch mode supply transformers as measurement devices. You can have isolation without using leftover transformers.

Comment: @IssamH isolation is for safety, yes, but if you ensure the circuit will not be accessible from outside then it's still going to be safe. If you worry about isolation during development, then you can isolate the circuit from the grid using isolation transformers, and use direct contact (dividers) for measurement.

Comment: @MarcusMüller I appreciate your help, I will think about other ways of doing isolation, such as using optocouplers

Comment: @RohatKılıç thank you for your help

Answer (score 1):

If the phone charger is a switching supply, the transformer can be used only in a switching circuit, not as a simple voltage stepdown.  A switching circuit to produce an output that is directly proportional to the input amplitude is more complex than you might imagine, additionally complicated because low-energy transformer magnetics are very weird.  Also, the zillions of switching circuits out there are useless because they are designed to do the exact opposite of what you want.

Plus, the overall circuit will be larger and obviously more complex than a simple linear transformer.

When you cut open a wall wart, switching or linear, *all* of the safety certifications vanish.  Better to purchase the smallest linear transformer you can find.  You want insulation and isolation that is tested and certified.

Is this project for work, school, or personal?

Comment: thank you for your answer, this is a university project. Can you tell me the difference between a transformer designed for smps and a linear transformer in terms of core design ? maybe a good link to read about it ? I will look for a linear transformer and see if I can find any

Comment: "low-energy transformer magnetics are very weird" does this also apply to linear transformers well ? is there a good book or link to read about these details?

Comment: The differences are many and large.  Size, shape, materials and alloys, composition, wire types, winding patterns, etc.  If you are at a university, they will have a library with books ranging from basic magnetics theory to switching power supply design.